# Capital letters in column title?

Tags: mysql, capitalization

Could someone tell me if it's alright to use capital letters in column titles in Mysql?

Sorry if this a dumb question, but i just couldn't find the answer anywhere else...

Thanks

Comment: If you had spent the 2 minutes you spent on your question on trying to create a new table with capital letters, you'd have had your answer sooner.

Comment: @kba It's a valid question, and for everyone else who may or may not have a database they can test with, it's faster and more trustworthy to have an upvoted answer to the question than to try it out themselves, and potentially make mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

See the MySQL documentation:

[Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

and

[Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

You can use upper case but names are case-insensitive on all platforms. You should not use two different cases for the same object within the same statement, though.